# MongoDB collection shorthand?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Newbie alert.All this while I'm using the below command to refer to specific collection as below

```js
db.collection('someCollection')
```

But example shared on this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/#up._S_unset), clearly there's a shorthand available as below

```js
db.products
```

So I go ahead and change it from `db.collection('someCollection').update(...)` to `db.someCollection.update(...)`, but i'm getting exception

> (node:51451) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from the doc is for mongodb shell. Which, although also using javascript, is a completely different environment from node.js driver. From a brief glance at the driver's documentation, looks like it does not support this sugar/shorthand.